# help_hook() Is not Dispaying Help icon on Drupal 7 Module Menu

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am Trying To Add Help Button On Module Menu . I have Doing Lots Off R&D but Failed . BTW Here is My Code

**my_first_module.info**

```
name = My Module
description = embedded Video Comment
core = 7.x
```

**my_first_module.module**

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */

function my_first_module_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#my_first_module') {
    return t('A demonstration module.');
  }
}
```

> I have Cleared Cache But help link isn't appear

Comment: have you enabled it :P

Comment: I just tried this and it is working.. I clicked 'help' when I enabled the module and on this path admin/help/my_first_module the message 'A demonstration module.' appeared. Is the name of the module folder : my_first_module ? I can't think of another reason why doesn't work for you

Comment: what  ???? Then Why Its Not Displaying with me  ..D you make any change

Comment: I didn't change a single character .. are you sure your module folder name is my_first_module ?

Comment: finally .. its working automatically .. i dont know how ??  just create a new module .. and its done .. :(

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the help module (from Core) is not enabled.